# PostgreSQL ANALYZE statisticts & Replication

Tags: postgresql

On my primary I ran a VACUUM then an ANALYZE on all databases, then when I check `pg_stat_user_tables`, the `last_analyze` column shows a current timestamp which is great.

When I check my replication instance, there are no values in the `last_analyze` column.  I was assuming this timestamp would also eventually populate?  Is this known behaviour?

The reason I ask is that after that VACUUM/ANALYZE on the primary, I'm running into some extremely slow queries on the replication instance.  I ran an EXPLAIN plan prior to the VACUUM/ANALYZE on a query and it ran in 5 seconds... now it's taking 65 seconds.  The EXPLAIN shows it's not using a lot of indexes that it should be.

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL has two different stats systems.  One records data about the distribution of values in the columns, this is transactional.  It propagates to the replica via the WAL.

The other system records data about turn over on the tables and data on when the last vac/an was done.  This system is used to determine when to schedule new vac/an (to prevent the first system from getting too out of date). This one is not transactional, and does not propagate to the replica.

So the replica has the latest column value distribution statistics (as soon as the WAL replays, anyway), but it doesn't know how recent they are.

Comment: And the solution is? More aggressive vacuum on the replica?

Comment: The solution to last_analyze being NULL on the replica is--don't expect it not to be be.  The solution to slow queries on the replica is the same as always, let us know the version and show us the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`.  In this case, seeing from both replica and master would be nice.

Comment: jjanes - thanks for the great reply... that all definitely makes sense.  Thanks again!